# Customizing KnockOut Mapping by data type

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a list of data that looks kind of like this:

```
 "containers": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Description": "B",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 2,
      "Description": "A",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 3,
      "Description": "B",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 4,
      "Description": "A",
      "Properties": {}
}, 
 {
      "Id": 5,
      "Description": "C",
      "Properties": {}
}]
```

Using knockout and the knockout mapping plugging, my goal is to create a custom mapping to create something like:

```
 "containers": [{
    "A":[{
          "Id": 2,
          "Description": "A",
          "Properties": {}
        },
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Description": "A",
          "Properties": {}
        }],
    "B":[{
          "Id": 1,
          "Description": "B",
          "Properties": {}
        },
        {
      "Id": 3,
      "Description": "B",
      "Properties": {}
        }], 
    "C"{
      "Id": 1,
      "Description": "C",
      "Properties": {}
    }]]
```

Where objects are group into arrays based on their description.

I tried something like this:

```
var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        var arrdata = [];
        if (!(options.data.Description in arrdata)) {
            arrdata[options.data.Description] = [];
        }
        arrdata[options.data.Description].push(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
        return arrdata;

    }
}
```

But it just but each object in it's own array, so rather than the three arrays I was expecting from my example I 5 arrays each of size one. How do to tell Knockout Mapping to merge the arrays or create a mapping that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var containers = [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Description": "B",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 2,
      "Description": "A",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 3,
      "Description": "B",
      "Properties": {}
},
 {
      "Id": 4,
      "Description": "A",
      "Properties": {}
}, 
 {
      "Id": 5,
      "Description": "C",
      "Properties": {}
}]

//Remap array of objects to object with arrays of objects
groupedByDescription = {};

containers.forEach(function(c){
  //Create object properties based on container description, and create array / push to array
  if(groupedByDescription.hasOwnProperty(c.Description)){
    groupedByDescription[c.Description].push(c);
  }else{
    groupedByDescription[c.Description] = [c];
  }
});

console.log(groupedByDescription);
```

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b7g7s5h9/9/

Does this help you? Should result in what u asked for, but not using ko mapping.